# My Node.js app on Heroku doesn't show up in browser Android phone

Tags: node.js, heroku

My Node.js app on Heroku doesn't work in the web browser on my Android phone. I get the error: 'there's nothing here yet'. The same error applies for all the browsers I've tried on android phones.

Any idea why this happens? Only one push in the right direction would be nice already!

Comment: I think this is not an android related problem , please edit the tags.

Comment: Alright, I've changed it